How to evaluate an expression of higher powers and roots using logarithms?
I am struggling with the following question from a Dutch algebra exam from the 1950s. The instructions are as follows:
Calculate with logarithms.
$$
    x = \frac{\sqrt[3]{(23.57^2 - 15.63^2)}}{{0.4453}^7}
$$
So far, I started off by taking the base-10 logarithm on both sides and then applied log-transformations, besides $a²-b² = (a+b)*(a-b)$, and I end up with.
$$
\log{(x)} = {\frac{1}{3}*\log{(39.2)}+\frac{1}{3}*\log{(7.94)}-\frac{7}{1}*\log{(0.4453)}}
$$
The result checks out. I am left with two questions.
I. Is this the correct way to calculate the result using logarithms? 
II.Can I simplify this further/use another approach that will lead to a more simple answer?
Thanks.

How did you get $7.92$ instead of $7.94$?

I don’t think you can make it simpler, and other than the error Moo points to, it looks fine.

@Moo Cheers, I have corrected that real quick.

Excuse me, I'm new to this notation of decimal point. Is this comma equal to decimal point?

@Gwen Thanks, indeed we use the comma instead of a decimal point. I made it all decimal points.

Based on the above, here's the solution with all steps, where I used the base-10 logarithm (but of course any other base would do).
\begin{aligned}
x & =\frac{\sqrt[3]{\left(23,57^2-15,63^2\right)}}{0,4453^7} \\
\log x & =\log \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{23,57^2-15,63^2}}{0,4453^7}\right) \\
\log x & =\log \left(\sqrt[3]{23,57^2-15,63^2}\right)-\log \left(0,4453^7\right) \\
\log x & =\frac{1}{3} \cdot \log (39,2)+\frac{1}{3} \log (7,94)-7 \log (0,4453) \\
x & =10^{\frac{1}{3} \log (39,2)+\frac{1}{3} \log (7,94)-7 \log (0,4453)}
\end{aligned}

I don't know whether you want to call this simplifying, but as you have taken log with base 10,
$$\log{(x)} = {\frac{1}{3}\log{(39.2)}+\frac{1}{3}\log{(7.94)}-7\log{(0.4453)}} \\
= {\frac{1}{3}[\log(392)-\log(10)}]+\frac{1}{3}[\log{(794)-\log(100)}]-7[\log{(4453)-\log(10000)}] \\
=\frac{\log(392)}{3}-\frac{1}{3}+\frac{\log(794)}{3}-\frac{2}{3}-7\log(4453)+28 \\
\log\bigg(\frac{\sqrt[3]{392×794}}{4453^7}\bigg)+27$$
